# populate checkbox dynamically in php

Tags: php

I am fetching Gmail contacts using OAuth API call in PHP and it's successfully done. But while trying to insert a checkbox with each email ID I am getting difficulties.
Here is the snippet of the `foreach` loop where the email IDs are populated:

```
$temp = json_decode($xmlresponse, true);
$links = array();
foreach($temp['feed']['entry'] as $cnt) {
    $links[] = $cnt['gd$email']['0']['address'] . "</br>";
}
?>

<span><?php echo implode("\n", $links); ?></span>
<input type="checkbox" name="links[]" value="<?php echo implode("\n", $links); ?> /><br />
```

It displays the email IDs, but there is no checkbox displaying here.  Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a checkbox input for each link item.

```
foreach($links as $link){
    //echoes the name of the id
    echo '<span>' . $link . '</span>';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="links[]" value="' . $link . '"/>';
}
```

Comment: while trying this code am getting some checkboxes...no email ids are displayed...

Comment: Where are the IDs? You have the $links array, and the $temp array. Where in the $temp array are the IDs?

Comment: @james...please check the code...I have added the line where $temp is called

Comment: Edited my answer. See above.

Comment: @james...thanks its working but the checkbox is not showing for the first item

Comment: Just the checkbox? Is the first item inside the $links array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71706/discussion-between-james-spence-and-user3305327).